# Not able to run bundle install or for that matter rails -v Rails 3.1.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ubuntu-10.04

I was having issues with RVM so I tried to uninstall everything (Ruby, RVM and Rails) and start fresh.

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.2 rc2 and I am working on Ubuntu 10.0.4. If I do ruby -v from the command prompt I am able to see the ruby version installed and same is true for rails -v.

However once I get into the application directory which and try to check rails -v I get this error

"Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

If I do bundle install I am getting this error

"bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Nothing seems to work and I am stuck in this recursive loop of uninstalling and installing.

Everything was working fine till I got an error linecache19 which requires Ruby >=1.9.2 (I was using 1.8.7 earlier). I installed RVM and Ruby 1.9.2, I had to uninstall RVM and 1.8.7 and I tried to install to install Ruby 1.9.2 as a standalone package. This obviously didn't work.

Please HELP!!

Comment: Looks like bundler is trying to use the system ruby. Try opening a new shell and running the bundle command again. You also check the output of `which bundle` to get an idea if it's using the correct bundler.  Also, FWIW, I think rbenv creates far less headaches (read, basically none) compared with rvm (which does all kinds of voodoo things to your shell).

Comment: @d11wtq I ran which bundle and got the output as /usr/bin/bundle. Even if I try to run bundle install from the new shell I still get bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory error. I have uninstalled RVM

Comment: @DevR You are still using the "old" system bundle. Have you tried forcing use of the RVM one?

Comment: @AllanNørgaard I have uninstalled RVM completely

Comment: @DevR Okay then I misunderstood you. What did you then install instead? What are you trying to make work, the ubuntu repository ruby/bundler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have uninstalled a previously installed Ruby version (in my case it was Ruby 1.8.7) and try to install latest Ruby version (I was trying to install 1.9.2) without using RVM. I manually deleted all the version of Ruby present by searching `$whereis ruby` from my command prompt.

After that I installed a ruby1.9.2. In my existing rails application I was getting lot of errors because the application creates a reference to the earlier installed ruby version (1.8.7) and try to find gems in the earlier installed location.

SO once you have installed a new version and want to run the earlier developed application search where your application is referencing the older version of ruby.

In my case I had to change the path in script/rails from `#!/usr/bin/env` to `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` .

You might also have to add the path of the latest Ruby which you have installed in path variables.